# Sql could not fetch record of a column when i join two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo, join

Please am trying to join two tables to fetch the record echo the records in one table.

The first is table 'customer' and the second is table 'beneficiary1'.

When, I try to join the tables then only get the records 
`(i.e receiver_id and receiver_name)` of `'beneficiary1'` but the table doesn't show the record (i.e profile_pictures) of the other table being 'customer'.

What could have caused this, i've tried all the codes i could think of!

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("bank_db");
$sender_id=$_SESSION["login_id"];

$res=mysql_query("SELECT c.* , b.* FROM customer c,beneficiary1 b 
                  WHERE c.id=b.sender_id 
                    AND b.sender_id='$sender_id' 
                  ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT 4 ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    if($row['profile_pictures'] == ""){
        $output6 = "<img src='default.png' class='img-circle' alt='image' width='40' height='40'/>";

    }else{
        $output6 = "<img src='src='uploads/".$row['profile_pictures']."' class='img-circle' alt='image' width='50' height='50'/>";
    } 
    ?>                          
    <tr>

        <td class="center"><?php echo $row['profile_pictures']; ?></td>
        <td><span class="text-small block text-light">0059687310 - <?php echo $row['reciever_id']; ?></span><span class="text-large"><?php echo $row['reciever_name']; ?></span><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
        <td class="center">
        <div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-transparent-grey dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

           <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-dark pull-right">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

FOR BENEFICIARY!

```
<php
include '_inc/dbconn.php';
$sender_id=$_SESSION["login_id"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM beneficiary WHERE sender_id='$sender_id' AND status='ACTIVE' ";
                $result=  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                while($rws=  mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                    .$rws[3]. //receiver_id
                    .$rws[4]. //receiver_name
                }
?>
```

FOR CUSTOMER

```
<php
include '_inc/dbconn.php';
$sql1="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id='reciever_id' ";
                $result1=  mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
                while($rows=  mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

                    .$rows[14]. //profile_pictures  
                }
?>
```

Comment: remove the single quotes around $senderid in the query

Comment: The images aren't showing still!

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @jophab The single quotes are not an issue

Comment: Have you tried running this query using phpMyAdmin or some similiar querying tool?

Comment: Have you lost interest... Gone to a meeting... taken a lunch break?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i actually ran the query on my mysql database and i realised the all the images where the same because i did not specify the WHERE Clause for the Customer table on the join. Please i added above the separate query for the both.

Answer (score -2):

Append with concat dot with double quotes for $sender_id

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT c.* , b.* FROM customer c,beneficiary1 b WHERE c.id=b.sender_id AND b.sender_id=".$sender_id." ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT 4 ");
```

Comment: Do you not know about automatic $var expansion in a PHP double quoted literal?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please i dont.What's that?

Comment: Can you show us the schema for these 2 tables please. Add this info to your question using the `edit` link

Comment: @RiggsFolly  How do i get the schema? and where can i run the sql table for taste?

Comment: Please do not recommend the usage of insecure queries - this one is vulnerable for SQL injection and should **never** be used

Answer (score -2):

For joining purpose I think you need to re-write your query on following way :

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT c.* , b.* FROM customer c JOIN beneficiary1 b ON c.id = b.sender_id WHERE b.sender_id = $sender_id ORDER BY c.id ASC LIMIT 4")
```

Try this.

Comment: Do you not know about automatic $var expansion in a PHP double quoted literal?

Comment: I changed my query to yours but, it didn't work neither.

Comment: Please do not recommend the usage of insecure queries - this one is vulnerable for SQL injection and should **never** be used